# Terminology for an extreme type of group action

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, terminology, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a $G$-set. Is there a name already used to describe the following scenario?

> The stabilizer of each point of $X$ in $G$ is either trivial or the whole group.

Hence, the orbit space decomposes as just a bunch of copies of $G$ and singletons, no in-between. The name "$0$-$1$ action" is lying on my subconscious but I don't know why and I don't recall where I might have seen it. Any references are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the points whose stabiliser is the whole group, $G$ acts *trivially*. On the points whose stabiliser is trivial, $G$ acts *freely*. There is no need for a name for the behaviour across all of $X$ because the action decomposes.

Comment: I was hoping for a short description of this scenario, but I do guess I'll be better off by simply saying that the desired actions decompose into a free and a trivial part.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza That actually seems nicer than the exact words I wrote here.